# Kindle - best way to save images

Tags: android, kindle

I have created a book that each page is a JPG picture (believe me, this is how the book is intended to be). This book is intended to be read in landscape.

This will be a kindle book, intended to be read on all kindle platorms (kindle 1, kindle 2, iphone, ipad, mac, windows and android). I don't have a kindle yet, but I have kindle app for iPhone and mac.

I have prepared the HTML structure to be used.

My question is: the images were created to be seen in landscape, and all images were saved in this format (I mean, the largest size is the horizontal).

If I create an HTML for kindle and all images are saved that way, the images will be scaled down, so they fit on the horizontal size of the device screen, right?

As this was the way this book was created for iPhone and iPad, I suppose that at least on Android users will have the option to turn the device sideways and the image will expand to fill the screen. But what about Kindle 1 and 2?

If I rotate the images 90 degrees CCW, kindle 1 and 2 will see the image at the maximum dimension possible but when the android user rotates the device, the image will rotate and the user will not be able to see it correctly.

How to solve that? What's the best way to do that?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is about how to ensure they display properly on the Android, you can put `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in your `<activity>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: thanks, but what I want to do is format it correctly so it will be seen correctly inside kindle for Android, kindle 2, kindle 1, kindle for mac, kindle for windows, kindle for iphone and ipad.

Comment: Oh, I don't know those platforms.  Sorry.